# PHP SESSION and COOKIE

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a login form with the following code

```
if ($does_user == 1)//Als het aantal rijen gelijk is aan 1, zorg wel met registreren dat er geen dubbele gebruikers in de database kunnen worden toegevoegd
        {
            //Extract de array naar strings
            extract($row);

            if ($acces_level == 1)
            {   
                if (isset($_POST["remember"]))
                {
                    //Cookie aanmaken met de id van de gene die inlogt
                    setcookie("user_id", $user_id, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");

                    //Naar de profiel pagina
                    header("location: profile.php?user_id=".$user_id."");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Session aanmaken met de id van de gene die inlogt
                    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;

                    //Naar de profiel pagina
                    header("location: profile.php?user_id=".$user_id."");
                }
            }
            elseif ($acces_level == 2)
            {
                if (isset($_POST["remember"]))
                {
                    //Cookie aanmaken met de id van de gene die inlogt
                    setcookie("user_id", $user_id, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");

                    //Naar de admin pagina
                    header("location: admin/index.php?user_id=".$user_id."");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Session aanmaken met de id van de gene die inlogt
                    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;

                    //Naar de admin pagina
                    header("location: admin/index.php?user_id=".$user_id."");
                }
            }
        }
```

and when it goes to the profile.php page it sends a id with the url. So i build a function when the user changes its id in the url u wil head to a 404.php
But this function is not working well and i dont know why.

```
function user_exists()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) !== $_GET["user_id"])
    {
        header("location: 404.php");
        exit();
    }
    elseif (isset($_COOKIE["user_id"]) !== $_GET["user_id"])
    {
        header("location: 404.php");
        exit();
    }           
}
```

The $_GET["user_id"] is equal to the SESSION or the COOKIE but it heads to the 404.php anyway, can someone explain to me why ?

Comment: isset() returns true or false, you are comparing a boolean to a string (which should alawys be false)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I can't believe I missed that. Pop that into an answer and you have my +1 right away :)

Comment: Ahh that was my mistake i thought i could compare those values. So first check if its set and then compare Thhx for the quick answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as intended:

```
function user_exists()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) && ($_SESSION["user_id"] !== $_GET["user_id"])
    {
        header("location: 404.php");
        exit();
    }
    elseif (isset($_COOKIE["user_id"]) && ($_COOKIE["user_id"]) !== $_GET["user_id"])
    {
        header("location: 404.php");
        exit();
    }           
}
```

Check first if the stored variable is empty and compare the content of it with the $_GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing using a *Equal to and of the Same Type* comparison.

GET Data is always posted as a string (that's just how it works) so you are probably checking an int against a string. Switching to `!=` over `!==` would probably do the trick for you, or you can do some fancy type juggling before you test it in the comparison to covert it over yourself.

Answer (score 0):

check if it is set, then compare...

```
if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) && ($_SESSION["user_id"] !== $_GET["user_id"])){...
```